# Table formatting using xltabular

Tags: tables, tabularx

I am having some issues with formatting the below table.

The first issue: It is not positioning after the text and instead is starting on a new page despite the positioning `!htbp`.

The second issue: The table is large but it is not breaking over to the second page. I am unsure about why this is happening.

Any advice would be great!

```
\textit{Table 2} outlines the structure of this document
\begin{table}[!htbp]
\caption {Document Structure} \label{tab:Document Structure} 
\begin{xltabular}{\textwidth}{|X|} 
    \hline
    \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{Chapter One: Introduction}                                                                                                                                                                                                 \\ \hline
    This chapter will introduce the project and provide the,reader with context of the subject along with the reasons for undertaking the,project and an outline of the project contents.                                                           \\ 
    \hline
    \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{Chapter Two: Literature Review}                                                                                                                                                                                            \\ \hline
    This chapter will review current literature surrounding,the subjects of this project this will explore the current systems and,theoretical systems that form the basis for this project.                                                        \\ \hline
    \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{Chapter Three: Technology Review}                                                                                                                                                                                          \\ \hline
    Throughout this chapter will provide a review of the,technology used in current systems and the technology that will be used for,the proposed system.                                                                                           \\ \hline
    \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{Chapter Four: Analysis of Current Systems}                                                                                                                                                                                 \\ \hline
    In this chapter a comparison of current systems will be,provided to form a platform from which to model the proposed system. This comparison,will be used to model the functionality of the system and methodology used,for testing the system. \\ \hline
    \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{Chapter Five: System Analysis and Requirements}                                                                                                                                                                            \\ \hline
    In this chapter the base functionality for the proposed system,will be discussed and a draft of its implementation will be provided in the,form of system and communication diagrams.                                                           \\ \hline
    \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{Chapter Six: Use Cases}                                                                                                                                                                                                \\ \hline
    Throughout this chapter some examples of use cases will be given. these use cases will for the basis for the modeling of system functionality going forward with the project. For the purpose of this project three use cases will be given. chapter,five.                                                                                                     \\ \hline
    \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{Chapter Seven: System Design}                                                                                                                                                                                                \\ \hline
    Throughout this chapter the system implementation will be,described and discussed based on the findings from chapter four and chapter,five.                                                                                                     \\ \hline
    \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{Chapter Eight: Software}                                                                                                                                                                                                   \\ \hline
    This chapter will discuss the software and how it was,constructed with reference to functionality and system requirements discussed,in previous chapters.                                                                                       \\ \hline
    \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{Chapter Nine: Implementation}                                                                                                                                                                                              \\ \hline
    In this chapter the implementation and integration of the,software into the hardware environment will be discussed with further,reasoning into the choices made on both software modelling and hardware,choices for this project.               \\ \hline
    \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{Chapter Ten: System Testing}                                                                                                                                                                                                                 \\ \hline
    Throughout this chapter a set of test methods will be discussed,,and results of these tests will be displayed. The chosen test method for this,project is user interaction dialogues.                                                           \\ \hline
    \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{Chapter Eleven: Evaluation}                                                                                                                                                                                                                \\ \hline
    This chapter will include a critical evaluation of the,system as well as any changes and limitations that were experienced along,with how these limitations were dealt with and how the project was adapted to,these changes.                   \\ \hline
    \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{Chapter Twelve: Conclusion}                                                                                                                                                                                                                \\ \hline
    In this chapter a conclusion will be drawn, and a review,of the objectives will be carried out to determine if the project achieved the, aims that were set out for it.                                                                          \\ \hline
\end{xltabular}
\end{table}
```

Comment: Please provide a **minimal working example** (MWE).

Comment: you have placed it in a `table` environment which is a non-breakable float.

Comment: also there is no reason to use a one column table, but here even more you have `X` specified but over-ride it as `c` on _every line_  so theer is no X column at all and `tabularx` has no way to force the table to teh specified width.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle, what would i use in place of `\begin{table}`?

Comment: nothing the package makes your tabular in to a longtable, see the package docs. But it isn't clear why you have a table at all, what is the difference between a 1-column table and normal text paragraphs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From looking at the example text that you have there, it looks to me like we are in the document structure part of your report/thesis.

Given the question, I would suggest [`longtable`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/required/tools/longtable.pdf) and [`booktabs`](http://ctan.uib.no/macros/latex/contrib/booktabs/booktabs.pdf) for what you are trying to accomplish.

Longtable allow you to span multiple pages and booktabs give you some nice control over rules.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{report}
\usepackage{longtable, booktabs}

\begin{document}
\textit{Table 2} outlines the structure of this document
    \begin{longtable}{p{\textwidth}l}
        \textbf{Chapter One: Introduction} &\\ \cmidrule[\heavyrulewidth](l{-5pt}r{20pt}){1-2}
        This chapter will introduce the project and provide the,reader with context of the subject along with the reasons for undertaking the, project and an outline of the project contents. &\\ \addlinespace[10pt]
        \textbf{Chapter Two: Literature Review} &\\ \cmidrule[\heavyrulewidth](l{-5pt}r{20pt}){1-2}
        This chapter will review current literature surrounding,the subjects of this project this will explore the current systems and,theoretical systems that form the basis for this project.  &\\ \addlinespace[10pt]
        \textbf{Chapter Three: Technology Review} &\\ \cmidrule[\heavyrulewidth](l{-5pt}r{20pt}){1-2}
        Throughout this chapter will provide a review of the,technology used in current systems and the technology that will be used for,the proposed system. &\\ \addlinespace[10pt]
        \textbf{Chapter Four: Analysis of Current Systems} &\\ \cmidrule[\heavyrulewidth](l{-5pt}r{20pt}){1-2}
        In this chapter a comparison of current systems will be,provided to form a platform from which to model the proposed system. This comparison,will be used to model the functionality of the system and methodology used,for testing the system. &\\ \addlinespace[10pt]
        \textbf{Chapter Five: System Analysis and Requirements} &\\ \cmidrule[\heavyrulewidth](l{-5pt}r{20pt}){1-2}
        In this chapter the base functionality for the proposed system,will be discussed and a draft of its implementation will be provided in the,form of system and communication diagrams. &\\ \addlinespace[10pt]
        \textbf{Chapter Six: Use Cases} &\\ \cmidrule[\heavyrulewidth](l{-5pt}r{20pt}){1-2}
  Throughout this chapter some examples of use cases will be given.\ these use cases will for the basis for the modeling of system functionality going forward with the project. For the purpose of this project three use cases will be given.\ chapter,five. & \\ \addlinespace[10pt]
        \textbf{Chapter Seven: System Design} &\\ \cmidrule[\heavyrulewidth](l{-5pt}r{20pt}){1-2}
        Throughout this chapter the system implementation will be,described and discussed based on the findings from chapter four and chapter,five. &\\ \addlinespace[10pt]
        \textbf{Chapter Eight: Software} &\\ \cmidrule[\heavyrulewidth](l{-5pt}r{20pt}){1-2}
        This chapter will discuss the software and how it was,constructed with reference to functionality and system requirements discussed,in previous chapters.  &\\ \addlinespace[10pt]
        \textbf{Chapter Nine: Implementation} &\\ \cmidrule[\heavyrulewidth](l{-5pt}r{20pt}){1-2}
        In this chapter the implementation and integration of the,software into the hardware environment will be discussed with further,reasoning into the choices made on both software modelling and hardware,choices for this project.  &\\ \addlinespace[10pt]
        \textbf{Chapter Ten: System Testing} &\\ \cmidrule[\heavyrulewidth](l{-5pt}r{20pt}){1-2}
        Throughout this chapter a set of test methods will be discussed,,and results of these tests will be displayed. The chosen test method for this,project is user interaction dialogues.  &\\ \addlinespace[10pt]
        \textbf{Chapter Eleven: Evaluation} &\\ \cmidrule[\heavyrulewidth](l{-5pt}r{20pt}){1-2}
  This chapter will include a critical evaluation of the,system as well as any changes and limitations that were experienced along,with how these limitations were dealt with and how the project was adapted to,these changes.  &\\ \addlinespace[10pt]
        \textbf{Chapter Twelve: Conclusion} &\\ \cmidrule[\heavyrulewidth](l{-5pt}r{20pt}){1-2}
  In this chapter a conclusion will be drawn, and a review,of the objectives will be carried out to determine if the project achieved the, aims that were set out for it.   &\\ \bottomrule
        \caption{Document Structure}\label{tab:Document Structure}
    \end{longtable}
\end{document}
```

This should give you the following outcome:
[image]

Comment: It should be noted that this only answers your question, I wouldn't use tables for this kind of thing.